# How to downgrade an EF code first migration for a live environment?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Say I have three migration histories (call it init, m1 and m2). I use package manager to generate all the migration cs files and when I run my website on a live environment, it will update the database to the latest version m2.

Say unfortunately we found a major problem with migration m2 on live and whats to roll back, then what is the right way to do it?

I know that I call run this on my local machine:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: m1
```

However, that will only update my local version of the database. For production environment, should I do something like manually delete the migrationhistory record on live or delete the `m2.cs` migration file generated by entity framework and redeploy the site?

Comment: Just script out the downgrade: Update-Database -Script –TargetMigration: m1 and run that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646488/downgrade-rollback-database-with-code-first-in-production-environment

Comment: Is that the perferred way to downgrade? but the m2.cs file is still there in the source code, as a result, EF will try to upgrade to the new version (m2) again when it runs? So I think I need to remove that m2.cs file as well?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it after you generate the script. Script will remove the records from __MigrationHistory back to rollback point. So you can either delete the migration(s) or you could simply correct the mistake with m3 or whatever and apply m2 & m3 consecutively. I prefer removing them.

Comment: You say that "i' will update the database to lastest version" - so you use automatic migrations? Then your easiest option is to generate m3 to fix the issues as suggested by @SteveGreene. Or you can change the connection string on your local machine to point to Live, migrate with `-TargetMigration` option, delete e.g. m2 (and generate m3 if needed) and deploy application.